# Openstack Failed to launch instance "test": Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. ]

Tags: amqp, openstack, openstack-nova

I try to make instance on openstack private cloud web UI. But it fails.The error code is

> Failed to launch instance "test": Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. ].

In /var/log/nova/nova-scheduler.log these errors are shown.

```
2015-03-16 03:32:26.824 1705 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-50543fb4-b607-4b50-9578-6435600d516b ] Delaying reconnect for 1.0 seconds...
2015-03-16 03:32:27.825 1705 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-50543fb4-b607-4b50-9578-6435600d516b ] Connecting to AMQP server on privatecloud:5672
2015-03-16 03:32:27.830 1705 ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-50543fb4-b607-4b50-9578-6435600d516b ] AMQP server on privatecloud:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.
```

I think my configuration is something wrong. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

As per the logs, nova-scheduler is failing while trying to connect to rabbitmq

INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit Connecting to AMQP server on privatecloud:5672
ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit AMQP server on privatecloud:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 30 seconds.

Please make sure hostname privatecloud is resolvable from the nova scheduler host and rabbitmq is listening on 5672 on privatecloud host.

Also verify that rabbitmq credentials are correct in nova-scheduler configuration file.